# Support 'text' as an alias for 'none' in syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

For years, it has driven me nuts, having to use ```` ```text ```` to deactivate syntax highlighting on most markdown-enabled platforms like GitHub, but  ```` ```none ```` or  ```` ```lang-text ```` specifically on Stack Overflow. Whenever I have worked more on platform A, I am bound to do it wrong on B and vice versa.

Would you please make sure that authors can use ```` ```text ```` as an alias for  ```` ```none ````? That would be a low-hanging fruit with a potentially big benefit.

Comment: Don't see anything wrong with adding an alias. Heck, I don't even understand why languages work without the `lang-` prefix but text doesn't.

Comment: They work without "lang-" prefixes, if their tags are associated with a language hint, as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/309898) (search for "Hinting: Tags" in the answer). However, that does not explain why `none` works, because I canot find any so-named tag on Stack Overflow, while I do find a `text` tag.